# When to use .jar, versus .exe?

Tags: java, jar, exe

In Java we can compile soure code into two types of executables: a .jar file, which is basically bytecode, and a .exe file, which is basically machine code. Under what circumstances would it be better to compile to an .exe versus a .jar, and vice-versa? Which one is faster to run? Thanks.

Comment: How you would compile to .exe ? You can create executable Jar not exe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason to create a `.exe` file is to make it easier to run an application or installer in Windows.

Java compiles to byte code which is then run in the JVM. Normally the .exe is just a wrapper that makes sure that the `java` VM is started and that the class bytes stored within the .exe (or any other location) are run.

Comment: But a .exe file is machine code, yes? Meaning that its faster than a .jar (because no need to translate from bytecode to machine code)?

Comment: Yes and no. An *.exe is maschinecode, but that does not automatic means itsfaster.

Comment: + The Classes within are compiled to maschinecode from the JVM (if needed)

Comment: Without going into specifics a .exe with precompiled code generally start up faster but it cannot do optimizations while it is running, so it depends. It depends on the VM implementation and compiler used for the .exe as well. Java is nowadays pretty spiffy for larger applications (but not for anything that utilizes vector calculations - i.e. games, video codecs).

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly. There are tools that can create .exe files out of Java executable jars, but that's in no way a normal feature of the JDK.

There are very few cases where an .exe file would be an actual necessity, since to run a regular jar you just need to have Java installed and properly configured.

A simple test to decide whether to go for a jar or an exe is to ask yourself "Do you need this to be an .exe file?". If you can't answer that in under 5 seconds, go with a jar file.